# How to add individual proportions to a stacked bar graph using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am currently writing a report based on a dataset called "esoph" (IIRC it's available in R, but I've moved it into a CSV), and I was able to create several nice graphics with my limited experience with ggplot2. I wanted to create a proportions stacked bar graph (all bars sum to 1), and I was successful, but I can't find a way to insert the individual proportions into each bar.

Here's a working example (in my actual code it's a little bit different, with labels in Portuguese, but this works just fine):

```
require(stats)
library(ggplot2)

data <- esoph

g <- ggplot(data, aes(x = ncases, fill = tobgp)) +
     geom_bar(position = 'fill') + 
     scale_fill_brewer() + 
     xlab("Number of cancer occurences") + 
     ylab("Proportions for each group") +                   
     guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Alcohol ingestion (g/day)"))

g
```

which generates this plot:

[image: img]

I've read that it's best to calculate the proportions and then feed them to ggplot, but I can't quite figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

To calculate proportions, you may add two columns in your *espoh* data frame. Basically, add a column that has the total value by ncases. If you are using `library(data.table)` , it will be something like this:

```
espoh[,.(total=sum(tobgp)),by=ncases]
```

Then calculate the fraction as :

```
espoh[,fraction:=tobgp/total]
```

Use the *geom_text* feature to add labels on your stacked graph:

```
+ geom_text(aes( x=ncases, y=tobgp, label=fraction, position=position_stack(vjust=0.5), colour="black")
```

Comment: `Error in [.data.frame(esoph, , (total = sum(tobgp)), by = ncases) : 
  unused argument (by = ncases)`

Comment: while using `esoph` directly (or calling it, like `data <- esoph`) I keep getting those errors. but if I extract the data from the CSV (which I'm doing) everything is fine